# how to use single and double quotes with brackets in php?

Tags: php, html

i have a problem using with single and double quotes with brackets in php

```
$nestedData[] = '<a href="JavaScript:newPopup('loghistory.php?logid='.$row['user_id'].'')"> History('.$countqry.')</a>';
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php?rq=1

Answer (score 4):

You need to escape the quotes or concat the strings:

```
$nestedData[] = '<a href="JavaScript:newPopup('loghistory.php?logid='.$row['user_id'].'')"> History('.$countqry.')</a>';
                                              ^ here your string ends
```

You can change to:

```
$nestedData[] = '<a href="JavaScript:newPopup(\'loghistory.php?logid='.$row['user_id'].'\')"> History('.$countqry.')</a>';
```

Or another option:

```
$nestedData[] = '<a href="JavaScript:newPopup('. "'loghistory.php?logid='" .$row['user_id']. "'" . ')"> History('. $countqry .')</a>';
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Its Working

Answer (score 1):

You can escape single and double quotes with \
Like this:

```
'You\'re'
```

Comment: Hi Sitethief,
can you please do modifications in my code?

Answer (score 1):

```
$nestedData[] = '<a href="JavaScript:newPopup('loghistory.php?logid='.$row['user_id'].'')"> History('.$countqry.')</a>';
```

**try the below code:**

```
<a href="JavaScript:newPopup("loghistory.php?logid='.$row['user_id'].'')"> History('.$countqry.')</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to output a single tick from within a litteral string then you will need to escape that single quote:

```
$a = 'Graeme\'s example';
echo $a;
```

Will output:

Graeme's example

Answer (score 0):

```
$nestedData[] = "<a href=\"JavaScript:newPopup('loghistory.php?logid='".$row['user_id']."')"."\"> History('".$countqry."')</a>";
```

Escape the quotes with \

this should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

```
$nestedData[] = '<a href="JavaScript:newPopup('".loghistory.php?logid='".$row['user_id']."'."')"> History("'.$countqry.'")</a>';
```